# How to Linq Average

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of items like this:

```
[
    {
        "AAA": 3,
        "BBB": 5,
        "CCC": 2
    },
    {
        "AAA": 3,
        "BBB": 25,
        "CCC": 6
    }
]
```

How can I produce a list that contains the average of each item?

This is the expected result:

```
{
    "AAA": 3,
    "BBB": 15,
    "CCC": 4
}
```

This is what I tried, but not working:

```
 var result = from x in items.AsEnumerable()
     group x by new { x.AAA, x.BBB, x.CCC } into g
                 select new
                 {
                     AAA_Average = Convert.ToInt32(g.Average(a => a.AAA)),
                     BBB_Average = Convert.ToInt32(g.Average(a => a.BBB)),
                     CCC_Average = Convert.ToInt32(g.Average(a => a.CCC))
                 };
```

.NET Fiddle link: https://dotnetfiddle.net/pZ6TGD

Comment: Your title asks how to Sum, but the body asks how to Average... Please [edit] your question to choose one. Also, you say your attempt is "not working", but not what that means. Are you getting an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To begin with, I believe you needed `Average` and not `Sum` as indicated by the Question title (as evident from your sample)

You could do the following

```
var result = new {
        AAA = items.Average(x=>x.AAA),
        BBB = items.Average(x=>x.BBB),
        CCC = items.Average(x=>x.CCC)
        };
```

Please do note that Average could produce a decimal value. If you need to round of the value, you could use `Math.Round`

Answer (score 1):

You can aggregate totals and calculate average in one go:

```
var average = items.Aggregate(
    new Item(),
    (acc, item) => { // calculate totals
        acc.AAA += item.AAA;
        acc.BBB += item.BBB;
        acc.CCC += item.CCC;
        return acc;
    },
    acc => { // calculate average (ensure there is at least 1 item)
        acc.AAA /= items.Count;
        acc.BBB /= items.Count;
        acc.CCC /= items.Count;
        return acc;
    }
 );
```

Benefit: single iteration through items.

Answer (score 0):

This way:

```cs
var result = new 
{
    AAA_Average = items.AsEnumerable().Average(x => x.AAA),
    BBB_Average = items.AsEnumerable().Average(x => x.BBB),
    CCC_Average = items.AsEnumerable().Average(x => x.CCC),
};
```